# Implementation of Isotropic squared exponential kernel with numpy

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I've come across a from scratch implementation for gaussian processes:
http://krasserm.github.io/2018/03/19/gaussian-processes/

There, the isotropic squared exponential kernel is implemented in numpy. It looks like:
[image]

The implementation is:

```
def kernel(X1, X2, l=1.0, sigma_f=1.0):
    sqdist = np.sum(X1**2, 1).reshape(-1, 1) + np.sum(X2**2, 1) - 2 * np.dot(X1, X2.T)
    return sigma_f**2 * np.exp(-0.5 / l**2 * sqdist)
```

consistent with the implementation of Nando de Freitas: https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nando/540-2013/lectures/gp.py

However, I am not quite sure how this implementation matches the provided formula, especially in the sqdist part. In my opinion, it is wrong but it works (and delivers the same results as scipy's cdist with squared euclidean distance). Why do I think it is wrong? If you multiply out the multiplication of the two matrices, you get

[image]

which equals to either a scalar or a nxn matrix for a vector x_i, depending on whether you define x_i to be a column vector or not. The implementation however gives back a nx1 vector with the squared values.

I hope that anyone can shed light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out: The implementation is correct. I just was not aware of the fuzzy notation (in my opinion) which is sometimes used in ML contexts. What is to be achieved is a distance matrix and each row vectors of matrix A are to be compared with the row vectors of matrix B to infer the covariance matrix, not (as I somehow guessed) the direct distance between two matrices/vectors.